# pandas to_csv — do not encode filename or path

Tags: python, pandas

How can I write a file to the filesystem whose filename isn't encoded?

Currently, writing `/myfolder/my file.csv` becomes `/myfolder/my%20file.csv`. I want the filename to be `my file.csv`.

Code snippet:

```
rs = (grequests.get(u, headers=headers, stream=True, hooks={'response': addFilenameToResponse}) for u in urls)
sp_results = grequests.map(rs)

for res in sp_results:
   byteStream = io.BytesIO(res.content)
   result_df = pd.read_csv(byteStream, sep=",", encoding='utf8')
   outputloc = downloads_folder + res.filePathFull + '/' + res.filename
   outputloc = outputloc.replace('/', '\\') # switching for Windows 10
   result_df.to_csv(outputloc, index=False, encoding=None)
   ...
```

I've tried outputting `to_csv` as `encoding=None` but this doesn't work. Beyond this, [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) do not show any other methods it seems.

The problem is, there's another legacy tool we're then reading in the filename from, and the tool re-encodes the encoded filename, resulting in `/myfolder/my%2520file.csv` (`%` encodes to `%25`).

Comment: How do you first set `outputloc`? You just started your code from the point you modify it.

Comment: @AmiTavory added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition of the `grequests` part seems to clarify the problem (which is not `pandas` related).

[`%20` is a url encoding for the space character](http://krypted.com/utilities/html-encoding-reference/). To remove it, you can use [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse). In Python3:

```
from urllib import parse

...

outputloc = parse.unquote(outputloc)
result_df.to_csv(outputloc, index=False, encoding=None)
```